# Mapas em Java: pegar chave a partir do valor

Tags: java, maps, collection

Olá,

Eu tenho um mapa de string para string:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
```

com uma série de valores

```
myMap.put("1","valor1");
myMap.put("2","valor2");
myMap.put("3","valor3");
```

Gostaria de saber qual é a maneira mais "elegante" de pegar a chave a partir do valor, ou seja, como se eu passasse `myMap.get("valor1")` e o método me retornasse "1", como se fosse o `get` já existente em "sentido oposto". Antes de implementar algo, gostaria de saber se já existe algo pronto nesse sentido.

Obrigado,

Comment: Os valores não vão se repetir?

Comment: pode assumir que não, ou pode devolver o primeiro que der match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, esta linha não compila :

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
```

Você não pode criar uma instância de uma interface. No seu caso, seria melhor usar um [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) uma vez que a ordem não importa :

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Além disso, de Java 7, você pode usar o operador *diamante* que lhe permite reduzir o código redundante quando se usa os généricos :

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Em termos da sua pergunta, de Java 8, você pode usar o [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) para preencher sua necessidade :

```
String key = myMap.entrySet()
                .stream()                       
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals("valor1"))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .orElse(null);
```

Aqui está o que fazemos aqui :

- Recupera os [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) de seu mapa.
- Filtrar o fluxo para manter apenas entradas cujo valor é `valor1`.
- Recupera primeira entrada correspondente.
- Recebe o valor da chave.
- Se nenhuma entrada for encontrado, ele retorna `null`.

---

Se o código  é para ser utilizado várias vezes, pode muito bem ser encapsulado num método :

```
private String getKeyByValue(final Map<String, String> map, final String value) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(value))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Não existe um método oficial pra recuperar a chave a partir do valor, mas você pode implementar:

```
public static <T, E> T getKeyByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {

    for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Chamada:**

```
getKeyByValue(myMap,"valor1") // 1
```

**Exemplo funcional:** https://ideone.com/Wrw2gf

Esse método retorna a primeira chave que encontrar, no link abaixo há a versão que retorna a lista com as chaves.

*Fonte: [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](https://techspreadwithshraddha.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value/)*

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também dobrar o tamanho da sua tabela, colocando todos os `valores` das `chaves` como `chaves` dos `valores`:

```
myMap.put("1", "valor1");
myMap.put("2", "valor2");
myMap.put("3", "valor3");

myMap.put("valor1", "1");
myMap.put("valor2", "2");
myMap.put("valor3", "3");
```

Dessa forma basta executar `myMap.get("valor1")` para pegar a chave do valor `"valor1"`. Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/cs2fLQ).

**Entretanto**, isso só vai funcionar para tabelas que mapeiam apenas 1 valor para apenas 1 chave. E também apenas para tabelas que não possuem os valores normais como chaves. Essa tabela **não** poderia aplicar essa técnica:

```
myMap.put("1", "valor1");
myMap.put("2", "valor2");
myMap.put("3", "valor3");
myMap.put("valor3", "noventa");
```